# How to with CPack generate the WIX package?

Tags: cmake, wix, installation, packaging, cpack

I used cmake 3.12.0. There are exists one cmake project that creates one console application. I add the ability of package generation to that cmake project:

```
# ... above cmake code for one console application creation
# below code that I add:

# pack
set (A_PACK_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "${PROJECT_NAME} - CMake Assistant Solution")
set (A_INSTALL_PREFIX Consolas)

set(CPACK_WIX_PRODUCT_GUID "F9AAAAE2-D6AF-4EA4-BF46-B3E265400CC8") 
set(CPACK_WIX_UPGRADE_GUID "F9AAAAE2-D6AF-4EA4-BF46-B3E265400CC7")

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "WIX")

include(CPack)
```

With other generators (NSIS, 7Z, ZIP, DEB) all works fine but with WIX appears followed error:

> ...path\files.wxs(11) : error LGHT0091 : Duplicate symbol 'Component:CM_C_EMPTY_INSTALL_ROOT' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.

Why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be caused by [this bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20177)

Basically you use `add_subdirectory(xxx EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)` where the subdirectory has a `install(... COMPONENT ...)` call. The installed files are excluded from the subdirectory, but still creates `COMPONENT`s, which are now empty and break wix.

As a workaround, you can add:

```
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL Unspecified)
```

in `CMakeLists.txt` to exclude all the empty components.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps any, I had this problem and found that I had INSTALL commands that specified only Release Configurations but then tried to build the package using the Debug build configuration. By just switching to building the package specifying the Release configuration all went as expected (Wasted most of an afternoon before I figured this out!)

Comment: I check this one, but it used the Release configuration scipt version for all actions (build, test, pack).